# how to i access activedataprovider in view

Tags: view, controller, yii2

In my controller I have this actionView, it contain result, how can i get the result into view page.
    $this->title = $dataProvider->vchr_name; this get error. how  i access the data provider in view. please help me.

```
public function actionView($id)
        {
            $query = new Query; 
            $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([

                     'query'=> $query
                                ->select(['vchr_name','vchr_actual_hours','vchr_worked_hours','vchr_month', 'year'])
                                ->from('tbl_payroll')
                                ->join( 'INNER JOIN', 'tbl_employee', 'tbl_employee.pk_int_emp_id = tbl_payroll.fk_int_emp_id')
                                ->join('INNER JOIN', 'tbl_payroll_month', 'tbl_payroll_month.pk_int_payroll_month_id = tbl_payroll.fk_int_payroll_month')
                                ->join('INNER JOIN', 'tbl_payroll_year', 'tbl_payroll_year.pk_int_payroll_year_id = tbl_payroll.fk_int_payroll_year')
                                ->where(['pk_int_payroll_id'=> $id])
                                ->One(),
                                ]);
                return $this->render('view', [
                   'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,   
            ]);
         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should accessing to the models  attribute of adataProvider

```
 $allModels = $dataProvider->models;
```

or

```
 $allModels = $dataProvider->getModels(); // for actual page
```

$allModels contain a collection of models  eg: for accessing first model you can

```
echo $allModels[0]['my_attribute'];
```

eg :

```
echo $allModels[0]['vchr_name'];
```

Comment: using this statement  $allModels = $dataProvider->models; i got this array                                          
   Array ( [vchr_name] => midlaj [vchr_actual_hours] => 240 [vchr_worked_hours] => 240 [vchr_month] => JANUERY [year] => 2002 )         echo $allModels[0]->vchr_name make an error;  how to  i get midlaj  from this array

Comment: I have update the answer  with a suggestion  .. hope is useful

Comment: echo $allModels[0]-['>vchr_name']; this shows undefined offset error, what it means

Comment: echo $allModels['vchr_name']; its working. thanks a lot

Comment: hello how to change number of columns in detail View dynamically in yii2